# z-index of non-flash video in webkit

Tags: css, video, safari, webkit, z-index

I am trying to get an embeded .wmv video to appear behind a CSS controlled drop down menu in webkit browsers (most importantly Safari 5 on Windows and Mac).

**<edit>** I've expanded my test files and am having the same issue with .avi and .mpg (which I suppose in unsurprising since I use the same html). Additionally I've got the issue with .mov files which I use slightly different html for. But I can live with no .mov support for now.
**</edit>**

I have tried changing the wmode to transparent but that doesn't fix the issue. I tend to use opaque as, with flash at least, you can then target the object better and I've not yet used a video that requires transparency.

Please note: this is not an issue with .swf or .flv, just .wmv files.

I have set up [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/pzBFC/2/) showing the issue and the html I am using. This example works for me in IE7/IE8/IE9/FF3.6.

If anyone can help I will be much indebted!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/pzBFC/19/

Credit:: http://www.vsellis.com/code/fix-dropdown-menus-that-fall-behind-embeded-video/

You could check the differences on how they embedded the video, on the other hand, I've added a quick fix on the CSS, setting values for z-index and positioning.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately it seems you have changed the file type to flash which isn't the problem I am having